# How to write this.handle click in functional component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I want to hide and show dropdown div On click using one satate. in this medthod all divs are opening at one click.

if I click button1 div 1 should open
if I click button2 div 2 should open

How to write this.click in functional component, please help me

```js
const [dropdownOpen, setdropdownOpen] = useState(false);
const handleDropdown = () =>{
    setdropdownOpen(!dropdownOpen)
}
```

```css
div{
display:none
}

.dropdown-menu.show{
display:block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" onClick={handleDropdown}>Button 1</button>
<button type="button" onClick={handleDropdown}>Button 2</button>
<button type="button" onClick={handleDropdown}>Button 3</button>

 <div className={`dropdown-menu ${dropdownOpen === true ? "show" : "hide"}`} aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
 Div 1
 </div>
 
  <div className={`dropdown-menu ${dropdownOpen === true ? "show" : "hide"}`} aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
 Div 2
 </div>
 
  <div className={`dropdown-menu ${dropdownOpen === true ? "show" : "hide"}`} aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
 Div 3
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have three divs, you need three state values. You can use an object, an array, or three different useState hooks.

Here's an example using an array:

```js
const [dropdownOpen, setdropdownOpen] = useState([false,false,false]);
const handleDropdown = (idx) => {
    setdropdownOpen(dropdownOpen.map((v,i) => i === idx ? !v : v)
}


<button type="button" onClick={handleDropdown(0)}>Button 1</button>
<button type="button" onClick={handleDropdown(1)}>Button 2</button>
<button type="button" onClick={handleDropdown(2)}>Button 3</button>

 <div className={`dropdown-menu ${dropdownOpen[0] === true ? "show" : "hide"}`} aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
 Div 1
 </div>
 
  <div className={`dropdown-menu ${dropdownOpen[1] === true ? "show" : "hide"}`} aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
 Div 2
 </div>
 
  <div className={`dropdown-menu ${dropdownOpen[2] === true ? "show" : "hide"}`} aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
 Div 3
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use an array state here. That seems to be the simplest way to do it for me. All `divs` and correspondingly `buttons` should have their separate state variable. And toggling them should do the trick.

To uniquely identify you might use a [`data-attribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to link a button to its div. I have used `data-reactid`.

To keep it generic, the below code just maps over the array to generate the different `divs`. The second `argument` of the map callback function is the index, so leveraged that.

```js
const [dropdownOpen, setdropdownOpen] = useState([false,false,false]);
const handleDropdown = (e) =>{
    let newArray=  [...dropdownOpen];
    newArray[e.target.dataset.reactid] = !newArray[e.target.dataset.reactid];
    setdropdownOpen(newArray)
}
```

```css
div{
display:none
}

.dropdown-menu.show{
display:block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" onClick={handleDropdown} data-reactid={1}>Button 1</button>
<button type="button" onClick={handleDropdown} data-reactid={2}>Button 2</button>
<button type="button" onClick={handleDropdown} data-reactid={3}>Button 3</button>

{dropdownOpen.map( (x,index) => {
return <div className={`dropdown-menu ${x === true ? "show" : "hide"}`} aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
 `Div ${index+1}`
 </div>
})
```

**Note:** The snippet does not work. I just copied yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleDropdown = (id) =>{
   if(id==='div1'){
   setdropdownOpen(true)
   }
   if(id==='div2'){
   setdropdownOpen(true)
   }
    if(id==='div3'){
   setdropdownOpen(true)
   }   
}


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" onClick={() =>handleDropdown('div1')}>Button 1</button>
<button type="button" onClick={() =>handleDropdown('div2')}>Button 2</button>
<button type="button" onClick={() =>handleDropdown('div3')}>Button 3</button>

 <div className={`dropdown-menu ${dropdownOpen === true ? "show" : "hide"}`} aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
 Div 1
 </div>
 
  <div className={`dropdown-menu ${dropdownOpen === true ? "show" : "hide"}`} aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
 Div 2
 </div>
 
  <div className={`dropdown-menu ${dropdownOpen === true ? "show" : "hide"}`} aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
 Div 3
 </div>
```